# sending email to all subscribed users, selecting from sql DB and sending, not working

Tags: php, html, sql, email

I have a HTML input form where a user can subscribe to a newsletter. They enter their first name, last name and email and they get added to a table in my sql database.

I  have created a second html form where the "admin" can enter a subject and a message in the body textbox and click send.

Now what is supposed to happen when they click send is, that subject/body to be sent to all the users in the sql database, but it is not working! Any help please? Code below:

```
<?php

$user = "example"; 
$password = "example"; 
$host = "example"; 
$dbase = "example"; 
$table = "example"; 

$from= 'example';//specify here the address that you want email to be sent from

$subject= $_POST['subject'];
$body= $_POST['body'];

// Connection to DBase 
$dbc= mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password, $dbase) 
or die("Unable to select database");

$query= "SELECT * FROM $table";
$result= mysqli_query ($dbc, $query) 
or die ('Error querying database.');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$firstname= $row['firstname'];
$lastname= $row['lastname'];
$email= $row['email'];

$msg= "Dear $firstname $lastname,\n$body";
mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $from);
echo 'Email sent to: ' . $email. '<br>';
}

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

I get the confirmation at the end "email sent to (and it will display the email)", but it does not actually send and also I get "undefined variable: to" on line 28.

(I have put example on purpose at the top)

Comment: very first question arises,are you working on localhost or on server?if localhost then is your mail configured?

Comment: If $to is undefined, it will be hard to send an email to the email address supposed to be in the $to variable :) Change $to -> $email.

Comment: "undefined variable: to" is correct cause: $to is really not defined.

Comment: @Abhishek I'm working on a server.

Comment: you can use mail function provided in php  http://ie1.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $firstname= $row['firstname'];
  $lastname= $row['lastname'];
  $email= $row['email'];

  $msg= "Dear $firstname $lastname,\n$body";
  mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $from);
  echo 'Email sent to: ' . $email. '<br>';
}
```

Your email address is stored in `$email` but you are sending email to `$to`. Your mail line should be:

```
mail($email, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $from);
```

Also, you should configure your server accordingly for `mail()` to work. Read more at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1):

change

```
mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $from);
```

to

```
mail($email, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $from);
```